# how much memory and resources consumes cacti?

Tags: monitoring

I want to monitor 2 production servers that delegate responsabilities in a distribuited maner, the most scarce resource in it is it's memory and data transfer.
I was wondering how much of these resources will i be consuming additionally if i install this tool ? or if someone has a suggestion on a different tool based on their expirience.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely dependent on what you are monitoring (how many hosts, how many variables on each), how long you want to retain data for, and how many people will be accessing the data.

A general answer for "two productions servers" is "not a substantial amount, but you shouldn't be running your monitoring software on the production systems anyway" -- Buy a low-power dedicated box (or rent a VPS) to run cacti, and possibly colocate it with Nagios or some other alerting system.